# regular expression to find lines that are subset of input string

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and tried my hand to formulate one but no success. The input string contains multiple comma separated words e.g. bat,cat,mat,rat. I need to find all lines that are subset of this string e.g. it should find lines which are subset of this string, but it should not return lines which contains anything else than these words.

input string

```
bat,cat,mat,rat
```

should match lines like:

```
bat    
bat,cat    
bat,mat,rat    
cat,mat    
mat
```

should not match lines like:

```
bat,pat    
bat,cat,pat    
pat
```

Comment: please show what you've tried

Comment: Using python for example you could split the line on ',' into a list then iterate through it to test each element for a match with r.'bat|cat|mat|rat'.  If any element fails to match the line fails and is not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:bat|cat|mat|rat)(?:,(?:bat|cat|mat|rat)\b)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/11

Use this if you dont want to match `bat,bat`

```
^(?!.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\b\1\b)(?:bat|cat|mat|rat)(?:,(?:bat|cat|mat|rat)\b)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/12

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do that:

1. Split input string by comma and store words in a hash set for quick look-up.
2. Split each line by comma and check if every word exists in a hash set. If yes, the line passes the test. If even one word doesn't exists - it doesn't.